# Several movies to DVD at decent quality?

Tags: dvd, ffmpeg

I want to put at least 3 or 4 movies, which are around 90 minutes, on DVD and still have good quality. So around 360 minutes to one DVD. What program and options should I choose to achieve best quality?

- I want to do in ffmpeg, I believe it to be the most powerful tool for the job.
- But if it can be achieved in nice GUI program which works in Windows 7 I do not mind.
- I also don't mind Linux application, I prefer one which works in Ubuntu (because I can [install Ubuntu from Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer)) or in Mandriva
- It could also be a program which works in any Windows, because [Linux has Windows emulator](http://www.winehq.org/).

**EDIT**:

- I have DVD player DVP3260.
- According to [manual from Phillips](http://www.p4c.philips.com/files/d/dvp3260_12/dvp3260_12_pss_aen.pdf) it can play MPEG1, MPEG2, DivX 3.11, DivX 4.x, DivX 5.x, DivX 6.0.
- It should play XVid too, but I do not have more information about it yet.
- I don't need to author it (create menu), player can browse/list files.

Comment: Do you want  to *author* a DVD (with a simple menu), or do you have a DVD player capable of playing back DivX/XviD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DVDFlick](http://www.dvdflick.net/) is a good Windows tool for encoding DVDs (and burning them afterwords). You can create menus within it, or use an external program such as DVDStyler to make better looking menus (if needed).